# How to make my option a default so if I clear my drop-down it is populated by the default

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make one option the default value so if I clear my drop-down it is populated by the default.

This is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function getEnvNames(result){
    $("#environmentName").empty();
```

**Here I clear the drop-down, but I want my default value to populate.**

```
var data = JSON.parse(result);
        $.each(data, function(key, value)
        {
            $("#environmentName").append("<option>" + value.name +" - "+ value.purpose + "</option>");

        });

}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<select class="body" name="environmentName" id="environmentName" class="body">                                                                                                                                                  
                        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>                                                                                                                                                          
                        </select>
```

Comment: `if (value.name == default) { append selected } else { append unselected }`

Comment: Or, if your default is always the given example: `.empty(); .append("<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>"); //start ajax call`

Comment: You could also do a `$("#environmentName").children().not('[disabled]').remove();`

Comment: selected="selected" disabled="disabled" this one showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If default selected value is `select an environment`, then use append function:

```
$('#environmentName').empty().append('<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Environment</option>');
```

Or if you don't want to remove the selected value (once the user changes the option)

```
$("#environmentName").children().not($("#environmentName option:selected")).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of clear your select box put a empty option will solve your problem

```
function getEnvNames(result){
 $("#environmentName").html('<option value="" >  Select An Environment </option>');

data = JSON.parse(result);
        $.each(data, function(key, value)
        {
            $("#environmentName").append("<option>" + value.name +" - "+ value.purpose + "</option>");

        });
}
```